# Does anyone know how to make watching status work with url?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Here is what i tried and didn't work: , I believe it's because it's youtube and needs to another site well i really don't know

```
bot.on('ready', () =>{
    console.log('online (1)')
    bot.user.setStatus('available')
    bot.user.setPresence({
        game: {
            name: 'JohnGameRage',
            type: "WATCHING",
            url: "https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCqajHrFNOsLsJFuGinahBUQ"
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What is `bot`? Please tag this with the library you're using.

Comment: I guessed it's discord.js, fix it if I got it wrong

Answer (score 1):

Your `game.url` property needs to be a URL to a twitch stream, [which is a limitation of the Discord API](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#activity-object-activity-types). Using youtube, unfortunately, doesn't work.

[Presence Documentation for Discord.js](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/PresenceData)

Comment: That's the library docs, and I would like to add that it's an underlying API limitation as described in API docs: https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#activity-object-activity-types